# NGK spark plug for timing advance

Tags: toyota, sparkplugs

What kind of NGK spark plug must be used when the timing on a 1990 Toyota Conquest 2E is advanced to 15° btdc?

Comment: NGK itself doesn't have any listings for the Conquest/Corolla 1.3L 2E, which I'm guessing you've already discovered, but http://bit.ly/2cDlL5V says NGK P/N BPR6EY-11. That part is on NGK's page although it doesn't list any Toyotas in its buyers guide. You can search for the P/N on http://www.partcat.com/ngk and make sure it matches your specs. NGK may have different materials available, platinum, iridium, etc. as well. The timing advance shouldn't affect the spark plug requirements; the important thing is that the plug fits and is correctly gapped.

Comment: Thanx for the answer,I will try NGK BPR 6EY-11

Comment: Thanx for the answer.I will try NGK BPR 6EY-11 cause of the timing that I had advance from 10°btdc to 15°btdc,hopefully it will make a difference in performance and acceleration and quicker start especially for cold start in the morning